# Lucene sorting in (keyword, alphabetical) order

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

How do I sort my search results in the following order (query phrase, alphabetical). To give an example, if I have  documents in my index, each with one field (foodname).  The food names of the documents are

1. fat chicken
2. chicken breast
3. chicken lasagna

If I query with the search word "chicken", I would like my results to be in the following order

1. chicken breast
2. chicken lasagna
3. fat chicken

Please note that the boosting factor for all these documents are the same in indexing stage.  Your help is appreciated

Thanks
-Venu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just give a high level overview of what I'd do. Consider using a food ingredients / recipes types dictionary & assigning higher boosting for words in the index that matches items in food dictionary.  And perhaps to go even further, assign weights to certain keywords in your food dictionary.  Here's an example of a [food ingredients dictionary](http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/ingredients).

Comment: @Joycechan, thanks for answering.  I am able to get the results.  However, the problem is that I have to give higher boost based on position during query time

Comment: I was more so thinking along the lines of boosing certain keywords in the index.  An implementation can look like this http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/01/payloads-with-solr.html

Comment: see this article in the solr wiki as well (How can I increase the score for specific documents) http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_increase_the_score_for_specific_documents